# Filter an integer using Like in BindingSoure.Filter or DataView.RowFilter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dataview, bindingsource

I've Trying to filter a `DataView` which have multiple columns where some is numerical values. Everything works perfectly when typing in a string but once a numerical value gets entered (like checking for courier #) it filters to nothing.

How My Data Displays before filter:
[image]

How My Data Displays after filter:
[image]

My Code is as followed:

```
private void tbxSearchCourier_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string outputInfo = "";
        string[] keyWords = tbxSearchCourier.Text.Split(' ');

        foreach (string word in keyWords)
        {
            if (outputInfo.Length == 0)
            {
                outputInfo = "('Courier #' LIKE '%" + word + "%' OR Name LIKE '%" + word + "%' OR Branch LIKE '%" + word + "%' OR 'Contact Number' LIKE '%" + word
                    + "%' OR 'Email Address' LIKE '%" + word + "%')";
            }
            else
            {
                outputInfo += " AND ('Courier #' LIKE '%" + word + "%' OR Name LIKE '%" + word + "%' OR Branch LIKE '%" + word + "%' OR 'Contact Number' LIKE '%" + word
                    + "%' OR 'Email Address' LIKE '%" + word + "%')";
            }
        }
        CourierDV.RowFilter = outputInfo;
    }
```

I've search for a solution on the web but can't find anything that works. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: You've put the column name between `''` which makes it as a string literal. Use `[]` around column name if it's a complex name. Also to compare an integer column with LIKE operator, you should first convert it to string.

Comment: Also to make the filter more readable, use String.Format to mix filter string and input values.

Comment: Thanks @RezaAghaei it was the damn `[]` that I forgot to use instead of the `''`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider these notes:

- You've put the column name between `''` which makes it as a string literal.
- Use `[]` around column name if it's a complex name.
- To compare an `integer` column with `LIKE` operator, you should first convert it to `string` because `LIKE` is an `string` operator.
- Also make sure your column name is `Courier #` and it's not the caption/header text.

**Example**

```
dataView.RowFilter = "Convert([Some Column], System.String) LIKE '12%'";
```

**More Information**

To learn more about supported syntax for filter, take a look at [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it does not want to work. Any other ideas why?

Comment: Surely it will work. Create a clean test and see the result. Here is the test which I did: `var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("A", typeof(int));
dt.Rows.Add(123);
dt.Rows.Add(111);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Convert(A, System.String) LIKE '12%'";`